# CSS margin-left behavior different between browser

Tags: css

I'm having some trouble with the margin-left CSS property. I have some nested unordered lists. This is what the list looks like with no change to the margin-left (in both IE and Chrome):

[image: No modification to margin-left CSS property]

I wanted to decrease how much each list is indented so I added this CSS code:

```
ul li ul
{
    margin-left: -25px;
}
```

This works fine in Chrome, which displays this:

[image: Correct display in Chrome]

However, IE 8 displays it like this:

[image: Incorrect display in IE]

I guess the origin of where the margin starts is different between the two browsers? How can I achieve the desired affect of decreasing the indentation of nested unordered lists among all browsers?

Comment: Set `margin-left` to a positive number. You just want a smaller number than the browser default. For starters, try setting it to zero and see how it looks. Then increase it as desired. Possible to provide a working example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into "zero-ing out" the margin and padding for ul and li's like so:

`ul,li { margin: 0; padding: 0; }`

As different browsers have different defaults. From there, you should be able to add your own margins and paddings as desired.

Comment: Setting padding = 0 and left-margin to a positive number did the trick! Thanks, Brian.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good thing to use always a CSS reset. This will avoid having differences among browsers. You could use a universal reset like;

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  /* etc */
}
```

Or going a bit deeper and use [Eric Meyer's](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) one or [anyone else](http://www.cssreset.com/). There are a few.

Anyway, in your case instead of play with negative margins, you should reset your margin and padding for `ul` and `li` elements:

```
ul, li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ or a standard reset css stylesheet

Different browser set different default settings.